# Compute the launchUrl in launchSettings.json?

Tags: asp.net-core

For developing a Core 3.1 web service, I require a current date in the launchUrl, e.g.

https://localhost:5001/api/Values?date=2020-06-05

Of course it is not that much effort to modify the date everyday, but still... Is it possible to define a computable launchUrl somehow? The alternative is to use environment specific default arguments.

Comment: If the date is always today's date, can't you simply remove this parameter and compute the date in your C# code? Or mark the parameter as optional, and default to today's date if not supplied?

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant with "default arguments". I was just wondering, if something more fancy is possible.